# Using Django for communication between APIS?

Tags: python, django

I am new in the world of programming. I know a little python and I am learning Django. I understand that Django is very useful for webpages backend.

But I don't just want a website or an webapp. What I want is to centralize all the operations of my company by communicating through APIS different applications such as CRM (customer relationship management), SQL database, bulk mail software, etc.

For example, I want that when I perform an action in my CRM software (sales), it activates a scrapy script that I am creating, which scrapes certain pages, and then stores information in my SQL database.

Can I centralize all of this through Django as if it were a central base that connects all my scripts and the communications between APIs?

Comment: which crm software you are using ? it's just to help you more

Comment: You might want to consider Puppeteer if you need to simulate some browser activity to get the data you need: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I would try doing any POST request to your Django server. In this code try doing a POST request to any other server. This should be all you need to get started building your central base.

Answer (score 0):

Django has the ability to do what you are looking for. A good starting point for you if you choose to pursue would be [DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/). Django REST framework is a powerful and flexible toolkit for building Web APIs.

However, I think you should also weigh the cost of maintaining and developing your own IPaaS (Integration Platform as a Service) with utilizing and conforming to some self-hosted / cloud-hosted IPaaS providers.

Some providers that accomplish what you may be trying to do can be found [here](https://alternativeto.net/software/zapier/?platform=self-hosted).